# Classification of Groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, math-history

Arthur Cayley classified all groups of order $4$ and $6$ in 1854, and groups of order $8$ in 1858. What about groups of order $2,3,5,7$?. These are prime numbers, and the most basic theorem in group theorem, namely Lagrange's theorem, implies that groups of prime order are cyclic.

Today, we know that for every $n\geq 1$, there is only one cyclic group of order $n$, up to isomorphism. (Also, there is only one cyclic group of infinite order.)

Had Arthur Cayley know about classification of finite cyclic groups? Can anyone give a historical information about the "*classification of cyclic group*"?

Comment: For $2$ and $3$, I would say they're so small that he probably knew that there were only one of each.

Comment: yes. it may be the case.

Comment: Given how trivial it is to classify cyclic groups (it is often given as an exercise for students when they first start learning about groups), I would be surprised if Cayley did not know it or at least figure it out while working on classification of small groups. A possible reason for not mentioning it explicitly is that it really is rather trivial. Of course, the triviality might just be when viewed with modern eyes, but hopefully someone with more knowledge of the actual history can say more.

Comment: I was also thinking this way. But, today, it is easy to classify groups of order $4,6,8$ (ref. Rotman's book), but I certainly do not believe that it was simple at the time of Cayley's classification process.

Comment: Classifying groups of order $4$ is also often an exercise for students being introduced to the subject. For the larger orders, the problem requires a more structured approach.